# Cypress | Is there a way for an 'it' test to begin where the last 'it' test ended?

Tags: function, authentication, testing, cypress, describe

So,

I was running a bunch of tests on only 1 describe and 1 `it`. Something like this:

```
describe("ProjectManager", function () {
    it("Many Tests", function () {

     //Test 1
     cy.get('blalblabla)'
     blablalbalb
     blalblabla

     //Test 2
     cy.get('blalblabla)'
     blablalbalb
     blalblabla

     //Test 3
     cy.get('blalblabla)'
     blablalbalb
     blalblabla

     etc..
    })
})
```

But now I decided to break down the tests into different `it` blocks, like this:

```
describe("ProjectManager", function () {
    it("Test 1", function () {
     cy.get('blalblabla)'
     blablalbalb
     blalblabla
    })

    it("Test 2", function () {
     cy.get('blalblabla)'
     blablalbalb
     blalblabla
    })

    it("Test 3", function () {
     cy.get('blalblabla)'
     blablalbalb
     blalblabla
    })

    etc..
})
```

The reason for that being that, it looks neat when running, because it will show multiple tests instead of only one.

MY PROBLEM: All my tests are done in one specific part of the website. To get there, I have to login, and then click on a bunch of stuff, and even write/save stuff, etc.

MY QUESTION: Do I have to do a `BeforeEach()` to do everything again after each `it`? Because thats just not feasible to me, it's too much stuff. Or is there a way for each 'it' to just continue at the same place the last `it` stopped and so I wouldn't even need the `BeforeEach()` method ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended for tests to depend on setup or output from other tests.

Refer to the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app), for detailed examples and recommendations from the Cypress team.

Comment: Yes, I know and I agree with you. But in this case, I thought it was a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add this:

```
testIsolation: false,
```

to:

> cypress.config.js

---

e.g. my full cypress.config.js look like this:

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'https://yoururl.com/',
    testIsolation: false,
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

*Cypress v12.3.0*

Comment: That's not how you structure your tests. If you need a setup for multiple `it()` in your suites like being logged in or similar, use `beforeAll()` or `beforeEach()`. Each `it()` should be isolated from each other, that's the core concept of testing.

Answer (score 0):

Using `describe()` and `it()` is recommended as it gives your tests a structure. Instead of `beforeEach()` you can use `before()` that executes once before all it blocks. Here you can write your code like open your website, log in, etc. And then you can write your tests in continuation with `it()`

```
describe("ProjectManager", function () {
    before(function () {
        //Visit website
        //login
        //click elements
        //etc.
    })

    it("Test 1", function () {
        cy.get('blalblabla)'
        blablalbalb blalblabla
     })

    it("Test 2", function () {
        cy.get('blalblabla)'
        blablalbalb blalblabla
    })

    it("Test 3", function () {
        cy.get('blalblabla)'
        blablalbalb blalblabla
    })

    etc..
    })
```

Comment: The problem with that solution, is that, everytime there is a new it() , it will have to do that whole process again? logging in, clicking elements, etc ? Isnt there a way to just have every it() continue where the last finished ?

Comment: Can you explain in words the steps that you would be doing? like eg. Open website, click element, so on..

Comment: So, in order to arrive at the place where Im doing my tests, I have to log in on the website, then I have to click on a button that will take me somewhere, then I have to open a toolbar, filter some elements, save my filter, load the filter and then begin the tests (around 10 tests). The tests include sorting the columns, verifying that the columns are in the correct order, renaming, deleting, etc. So If I had to do all those steps for every one of the 10 tests, its just too much. Is there a way just for one it() to start where the last it() finished?

Comment: If you write uptil load the filter in the `before()` section and then continue your tests in it. Like sorting the columns in one `it()`and then verifying that the columns in the next it block and so on.. Would this work ?

Comment: Or there are some portion of the code that you want to reuse in all or some of the it() blocks ?

Comment: I wanted to just start the next it() where the last one ended. Without having to re-do any steps. Just to continue, as if the it() didnt exist. The only reason I want the it() is to visually separate the tests when they are running.

Comment: You can do it like that in multiple it(). Write uptil wherever you want in first it() and then continue from second it(). Dont use beforeEach() it will execute before every it. Use before it executes once before all it Or dont use of any of them, simple write everything under one of the it() block.

Comment: Yes, thats what I am doing, Im using only one it() block. But it would be nice to have multiple it() blocks, so the tests would be separate.